# Value disappears at the table cells - Python/pandastable

Tags: python, tkinter

I double-click a cell, enter any value in the cell, but the value disappears. How to solve it?

Run the code to understand the case.

```
from pandastable import Table
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
t_frame=Frame(root)
t_frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

table = Table(t_frame, model=None, width=None, height=None,
              rows=5, cols=5, showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True)

table.show()

root.mainloop()
```

[look at the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZalS.png)

Comment: What do you mean by _the value does not remain_?

Comment: When I click on any cell, I can enter the value, ok.
But when I click another, the previous value disappears. :( @AMC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hit enter the cell value remains, probably that's a trigger required to update the values in the cell.

You can handle left clicks by overriding the left-click method using your custom logic, as explained at [pandastable examples](https://pandastable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html)

```
from pandastable import Table, TableModel
class MyTable(Table):
    """Custom table class inherits from Table. You can then override required methods"""
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kwargs):
        Table.__init__(self, parent, **kwargs)
        return

    def handle_left_click(self, event):
        """Example - override left click"""
        #do custom code here
        pass
```